# flutter customPaint scale issue

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

import photo from gallery and draw polygon on photo and sacled to fit in customPaint, i want to save the photo with the original scale but  save photo to original size and drawn polygon remain in same size and postion is also not correct..I have scaled imported photo and when i scaled the polygon with the same scale size of the polygon reduce and position is also not correct [first one is result after save and second one is how i draw]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NUxV.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eQ6U.jpg)

```
    void saveImageWithPolygons(LinePainter linePainter) async {
  try {
    PermissionStatus storagePermissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();

    if (storagePermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      Directory? appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

      if (_image != null) {
        final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
        final canvas = Canvas(recorder);
        final paint = Paint();

        // Draw the image
        final scaleX = (_image!.width.toDouble() / 2);
        final scaleY = (_image!.height.toDouble() / 2);
        final scaledImageRect = Rect.fromPoints(
          const Offset(0, 0),
          Offset(_image!.width.toDouble() * scaleX, _image!.height.toDouble() * scaleY),
        );
        canvas.drawImageRect(
          _image!,
          Rect.fromPoints(
            Offset.zero,
            Offset(_image!.width.toDouble(), _image!.height.toDouble()),
          ),
          scaledImageRect,
          paint,
        );
       
      linePainter.paint(canvas, Size(_image!.width.toDouble() * scaleX, _image!.height.toDouble() * scaleY));

        // End drawing
        final picture = recorder.endRecording();
        final img = await picture.toImage(
          (_image!.width * scaleX).toInt(),
          (_image!.height * scaleY).toInt(),
        );
        final byteData = await img.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

        if (byteData != null) {
          final buffer = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
          final filePath = '${appDir!.path}/image_with_polygons_and_lines.png';

          await File(filePath).writeAsBytes(buffer);
          print('Image saved at: $filePath');
        }
      }
    } else {
      print('Storage permission denied.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error creating folder or saving data: $e');
  }
}
```

```
    final scaleY = size.height / image.height;

  
    final scaledImageRect = Rect.fromPoints(
      const Offset(0, 0),
      Offset(image.width.toDouble() * scaleX, image.height.toDouble() * scaleY),
    );

    canvas.drawImageRect(
      image,
      Rect.fromPoints(
        Offset.zero,
        Offset(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
      ),
      
      scaledImageRect,
      paint,
    );

    final scaledPolygons = polygons.map((polygon) {
     final scaleA = (size.width / image.width) ;
     final scaleB = (size.height / image.height)  ;
      return Polygon(
        points: polygon.points
            .map((point) => Offset(point.dx * scaleA, point.dy * scaleB))
            .toList(),
        color: polygon.color,
      );
    }).toList();
    print('$scaleX');
    print('$scaleY');
    print('$scaledPolygons');
    print('width:$image.width');
    print('size:$size');
    
    final fillPaint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    for (final polygon in scaledPolygons) {
      fillPaint.color = polygon.color.withOpacity(0.5);

      final path = Path();
      final borderPath = Path(); // Define the path here

      String label1 = 'x';
      String label2 = 'x2';
      String label3 = 'y2';
      String label4 = 'y';

      for (int i = 0; i < polygon.points.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          path.moveTo(polygon.points[i].dx, polygon.points[i].dy);
          borderPath.moveTo(polygon.points[i].dx, polygon.points[i].dy);
        } else {
          path.lineTo(polygon.points[i].dx, polygon.points[i].dy);
          borderPath.lineTo(polygon.points[i].dx, polygon.points[i].dy);
        }

        // Draw labels at specific points
        if (i == 0) {
          canvas.drawCircle(polygon.points[i], 5.0, dotPaint);
          drawText(
              canvas, Offset(polygon.points[i].dx - 10, polygon.points[i].dy - 15), label1);
        } else if (i == 1) {
          canvas.drawCircle(polygon.points[i], 5.0, dotPaint);
          drawText(
              canvas, Offset(polygon.points[i].dx - 10, polygon.points[i].dy - 15), label2);
        } else if (i == 2) {
          canvas.drawCircle(polygon.points[i], 5.0, dotPaint);
          drawText(
              canvas, Offset(polygon.points[i].dx - 10, polygon.points[i].dy - 15), label3);
        } else if (i == 3) {
          canvas.drawCircle(polygon.points[i], 5.0, dotPaint);
          drawText(
              canvas, Offset(polygon.points[i].dx - 10, polygon.points[i].dy - 15), label4);
        }
```